# SQL query for adding column value to compare with other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

```
table_inventory
    List item
    inventory_rack_key(primarykey)
    node_key
    rack_id
    inventory_item_key
    in_coming_qty,locked_qty
    quantity

table_item
    inventory_item_key(primary key)
    item_id,product_zone
```

The table example are provided here [DB TABLES](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AltIfHyzagUAdGVwTmE2SXdvMlNkOXBKcHZIaHJEZkE#gid=0)
I need query to find out those items for which **(net_qty)** i.e difference b/w sum of `in_coming_qty` & `quantity` & `locked_qty` is negative. arranged by `node_key,rack_id, item_id,net_qty`

**Note:** each distinct set `{node_key,rack_id, item_id,net_qty}` will have only 1 row in output.
For ex `:{node_key,rack_id, item_id}` = {ABD101,RK-01,562879} has 4 rows in **table_inventory**
but in output net_qty= -78(single row) .

The query I made is giving me result but can we do it in some other way?

```
SELECT l.node_key, 
       l.rack_id, 
       i.item_id, 
       ( SUM(l.quantity + l.in_coming_qty) - SUM(l.locked_qty) ) AS net_qty 
FROM   table_inventory l, 
       table_item i 
WHERE  l.inventory_item_key = i.inventory_item_key 
GROUP  BY l.node_key, 
          l.rack_id, 
          i.item_id 
HAVING SUM(l.quantity + l.in_coming_qty) - SUM(l.locked_qty) < 0
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using?  MSSQL, Oracle, etc?

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly familiar with Oracle syntax, but I know that Oracle supports indexes on functions.  I'm not sure if it will be used, since there is grouping involved, but you may wish to look into creating an index for this query if performance of the query becomes an issue.  A guess at the syntax used to create the index would be:

```
Create index net_qty on table_inventory(SUM(quantity + in_coming_qty) - SUM(locked_qty));
```

You can search for "Oracle function based index" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we can additionally GROUP BY `inventory_item_key` without changing the result. If we can further assume that there are no (or few) rows in `table_inventory` without a matching row in `table_item`, then this query should be a bit faster:

```
SELECT l.node_key
      ,l.rack_id
      ,i.item_id
      ,net_qty
FROM   table_item i
JOIN  (
    SELECT inventory_item_key, node_key, rack_id 
          ,SUM(quantity + in_coming_qty - locked_qty) AS net_qty 
    FROM   table_inventory
    GROUP  BY inventory_item_key, node_key, rack_id
    HAVING SUM(quantity + in_coming_qty - locked_qty) AS net_qty < 0
    ) l USING (inventory_item_key)
```

#### Major points:

- By aggregating and filtering the values `table_inventory` before the `JOIN`, fewer join-operations have to be made.
- I simplified your quantity aggregation to `SUM(quantity + in_coming_qty - locked_qty)`. the other possibility would be `SUM(quantity) + SUM(in_coming_qty) - SUM(locked_qty)`. Either way makes more sense that the mixture you had. You would have to test which is fastest.
- An explicit `JOIN` clause is preferable in SQL if applicable. In this case you can further simplify the syntax to `USING (inventory_item_key)`.

The index @Chris proposes is impossible. Oracle has no way of knowing how to group these values. You need an index on `table_item.inventory_item_key`. Other than that I am not sure how to index aggregated values.

If speed is imperative and the values in table_inventory do not change very often, you could create a [materialized view](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~melody/courses/Fall2001CSCI379/DOC/server.815/a67775/ch2.htm) out of the sub-query `l` or the whole query. This would be a decisive speed-up.